# How to resolve this "Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'soap:Envelope'., Line '2', Column '63' "

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to validate xml against xsd in freeformatter but getting above error, please help me out to solve this, I tried adding `<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>` but doesn't work

**my xml :**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
        <m:GetStockPrice>
            <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
        </m:GetStockPrice>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**my xsd :**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/stock" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
  <xs:element name="Envelope">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Body">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="GetStockPrice">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="StockName" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:attribute name="encodingStyle" type="xs:string" /> 
</xs:schema>
```

please help me to solve this, thanks...

Comment: I think it is not wise to recreate the soap envelope structure in your own xsd to validate the message. better to make it a 2 step validation. first validate the message against the given soap xsd to ensure you received a well formed soap message. then extract the content from the body and or header and validate that against it's own xsd.

Comment: Thanks for replay @martijn , please share me any leads so that i can follow